# How can I create a cross-browser pure CSS flip animation?

Tags: css, animation, cross-browser, flip

So I've created a CSS flip animation. My problem is, that it looks totally different in latest browsers of Chrome, FF, and IE. How should I modify the css, to work perfectly in these modern browsers? Thanks!

Here is the working example:

[jsfiddle](http://tinyurl.com/m5bjnes)

Comment: Ditch all the [obsolete `-moz-` prefixes](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions). And IE10/11 [don't support `preserve-3d`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d), explaining their issues.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Removed -moz. All right IE is fine then. But in FF the movement is a bit "dizzy" when the animation is at the end. Why? :(